# Send a message to channel if a user switches voice channel

Tags: discord, discord.io

I tried it on this way, but the bot gives me an error:

```
let newUserChannel = newMember.voiceChannel 
                               ^ 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'voiceChannel' of undefined
```

```js
bot.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
  let newUserChannel = newMember.voiceChannel
  let oldUserChannel = oldMember.voiceChannel


  if(oldUserChannel === undefined && newUserChannel !== undefined) {

    bot.sendMessage({
           to: "475330828466126848",
           message: "User went form Channel" + oldUserChannel + "to the new" 
           + newUserChannel + "Channel"
    });

  }
})
```

It does not work.

My goal is to log all voice channel switches in a single text channel I made for that.

---

```
var Discord = require('discord.js');
var logger = require("winston");
var auth = require("./auth.json");
// Configure logger settings
logger.remove(logger.transports.Console);
logger.add(new logger.transports.Console, {
colorize: true});
logger.level = "debug";

// Initialize Discord Bot
var bot = new Discord.Client({
token: auth.token,
autorun: true
});

bot.on("ready", function (evt) {
logger.info("Connected");
logger.info("Logged in as: ");
logger.info(bot.username + " – (" + bot.id + ")");
});

bot.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
  let newUserChannel = newMember.voiceChannel
  let oldUserChannel = oldMember.voiceChannel


  if(!oldUserChannel && newUserChannel) {

    bot.channels.get('475330828466126848').send("User went form Channel" + oldUserChannel.name + "to the new" 
           + newUserChannel.name + "Channel");

  }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create Channel Switch Logger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51688716/create-channel-switch-logger)

Answer (score 0):

[`bot.sendMessage`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=sendMessage) is deprecated.

Try this one:

```
    bot.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
  let newUserChannel = newMember.voiceChannel
  let oldUserChannel = oldMember.voiceChannel


  if(!oldUserChannel && newUserChannel) {

    bot.channels.get('475330828466126848').send("User went form Channel" + oldUserChannel.name + "to the new" 
           + newUserChannel.name + "Channel");

  }
})
```

Please specify your error next time.
I used the the [`.send`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=send) property to send your message to this channel.

Comment: Hey man ;) Thx for answering. Here still the same error:   let newUserChannel = newMember.voiceChannel
                                 ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'voiceChannel' of undefined

Comment: What version of discord.js are you currently using?

Comment: Where I see that? I think I have not all includes ready... Here my includes var Discord = require("discord.io");
var logger = require("winston");
var auth = require("./auth.json");

Comment: You tagged this question 'discord.js', but you're using 'discord.io'. That's a major difference, we can't help you if you don't tell us

Comment: You added the tag "discord.js" to your question so I thought you use discord.js as your library for your bot but you aren't. That's the reason why you have this error.

Comment: Sorry guys, but I started today and Iam no well informed...So I need to remove discord.io and add discord.js?

Comment: You have 2 possibilities. You start using discord.js and this code that I gave you will work or you create a new question with the discord.io tag and ask your question again

Comment: You need to replace `var Discord = require('discord.io')` in `var Discord = require('discord.js')` but more you can read in the discord.js docs: https://discord.js.org

Comment: I submitted an edit with the tag fix, so that it will be displayed in the right category. If you'll have other questions about discord.js, please remember to use the right tag ;)

Comment: I posted my whole bot.js. When i switch channel, noting happens. I also dont get errors. Also the logger text is not apperaing